# Displaying user avatar or default avatar on search

Tags: php, mysql

Im having a problem with my PHP search script. I'm building a social networking site where one can search for a user, an event or a club. I would like the search results to display a user avatar thumb or a default thumb if none has been uploaded.
Im testing on localhost.
User avatar's are stored in the User_Images `(c:\wamp\www\NNL\User_Images)`folder while the default avatar is stored in `c:\wamp\www\NNL\Style\Images\default_avatar.png.`

The following is my PHP code:

```
<?php
while ($row_user = mysql_fetch_assoc($user))
{
  echo "\n<table width='500' border='0'>";
  echo "\n\t<tr>";
  echo "<td width='50' height='50' align='center' valign='middle'><a href='user_view.php?user_id=".$row_user['user_id']."'>
  <img src=User_Images/$row_user[picture_thumb_url] !=''? $row_user[picture_thumb_url]: '../Style/Images/default_avatar.png'
  border='0' height='50' width='50'/></a></td>";
  echo "<td width='140' class='ordinary_text_12'>" .$row_user['user_first_name']. "</td>";
  echo "<td width='140' class='ordinary_text_12'>" .$row_user['user_last_name']. "</td>";
  echo "<td width='140' class='ordinary_text_12'>" .$row_user['username']. "</td>";
  echo "<td width='30'><a class='text_12_link_green' href='user_view.php?user_id=".$row_user['user_id']."'>View</a></td>";
  echo "\n\t</tr>";
  echo "\n</table>";
}
?>
<?php
while ($row_event = mysql_fetch_assoc($event))
{
  echo "\n<table width='500' border='0'>";
  echo "\n\t<tr>";
  echo "<td width='50' height='50' align='center' valign='middle'><a href='#table_index.php'>
  <img src='Images/$row_event[event_thumb_url]' border='0' height='50' width='50'/></a></td>";
  echo "<td width='140' class='ordinary_text_12'>" .$row_event['event_name']. "</td>";
  echo "<td width='140' class='ordinary_text_12'>" .$row_event['event_venue']. "</td>";
  echo "<td width='140' class='ordinary_text_12'>" .$row_event['event_date']. "</td>";
  echo "<td width='30'><a class='text_12_link_green' href='#user_view.php?user_id=".$row_user['username']."'>View</a></td>";
  echo "\n\t</tr>";
  echo "\n</table>";
}
?>
<?php
while ($row_establishment = mysql_fetch_assoc($establishment))
{
  echo "\n<table width='500' border='0'>";
  echo "\n\t<tr>";
  echo "<td width='50' height='50' align='center' valign='middle'><a href='#table_index.php'>
  <img src='Establishment_Images/$row_establishment[establishment_thumb_url]' border='0' height='50' width='50'/></a></td>";
  echo "<td width='140' class='ordinary_text_12'>" .$row_establishment['establishment_name']. "</td>";
  echo "<td width='140' class='ordinary_text_12'>" .$row_establishment['location_name']. "</td>";
  echo "<td width='140' class='ordinary_text_12'>" .$row_establishment['establishment_pricing']. "</td>";
  echo "<td width='30'><a class='text_12_link_green' href='#user_view.php?user_id=".$row_user['username']."'>View</a></td>";
  echo "\n\t</tr>";
  echo "\n</table>";
}
?>
```

The problem is in the `$row_user` while loop where im trying to echo `$row_user` thumb. Right now, if a user has an avatar, it displays the image, however it returns no image at all if a user has no avatar. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: What are you *expecting* it to return if the user has no avatar?

Comment: I want it to return a default image that I have stored in a folder. The image is called default_avatar.png. See top paragraph. I have used similar code in the user profile pages but cant get it to work in this one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this although it's not exactly readable.

```
echo "<td width='50' height='50' align='center' valign='middle'><a href='user_view.php?user_id=".$row_user['user_id']."'>
  <img src=User_Images/" . ( $row_user['picture_thumb_url'] != '' ? $row_user['picture_thumb_url'] : '../Style/Images/default_avatar.png' ) . " border='0' height='50' width='50'/></a></td>";
```

You're best of doing the conditional beforehand then echo the variable:

Updated:

```
$thumbnail = $row_user['picture_thumb_url'] != '' ? $row_user['picture_thumb_url'] : '../Style/Images/default_avatar.png';

echo "<td width='50' height='50' align='center' valign='middle'><a href='user_view.php?user_id=".$row_user['user_id']."'>
      <img src=User_Images/$thumbnail border='0' height='50' width='50'/></a></td>";
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The not exactly readable works good. However, on your second method, how will I echo the variable thumbnail and the default and selected images are found in different folders?

Comment: sorry, just update the path to what you had it as previously. it should work ../Style/Images/default_avatar.png

Comment: Works like a charm Nick. Cheers for the help. Im kinda new to PHP

Answer (score 1):

You cannot put an 'if' statement into your 'echo'.

Go this way:

```
if($row_user[picture_thumb_url] !='')
   $thumb = $row_user[picture_thumb_url];
else
   $thumb = '../Style/Images/default_avatar.png';
```

And then:

```
echo "<img src=\"$thumb\">";
```

Comment: Thanks Jonathan. Let me try this.